# Session variables not being created if the user doesn't log out before logging back in

Tags: php, session, session-variables

When the user logs in, multiple session variable are created and work perfectly. 
When they sign out and log in again it works.

However, when someone quits out of their browser without signing out, the next time they log in no session variables are created.

To sign out, one goes to my logout.php file. The code in my logout.php file is:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=".000001;url=index.php">'; 
?>
```

I've tried pasting the code at the start of my index.php (where the login form is) but it doesn't work unless you go to the logout.php file.

Why is this and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible situations:

**First and main reason:**
If you have already started session_start(), server may be dump error, while you trying to create new, if your errors are off, you can't see them.

**Second:** You do check before session destroy.

Answer (score 0):

You are destroying the session before you are making sure that no session variables remain.

I would delete all of the session variables first before you destroy it, to be safe, because sometimes some get left behind.  You can do this like so

```
if (isset($_SESSION['/*whatever session variables  you are using*/'])) { 

    $_SESSION = array();

    session_destroy();
 }
```

Also if you are using any cookies for any reason (though this may not be the case), you need to make sure those are also deleted.  something like this:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {

    setcookie(session_name(),'',time() - 3600);
    }
```

Comment: if no session variables are set, assuming you have entered the correct session variables into the `$_SESSION['']` check,  then you should be;  that means that none are being stored, so there should be no problem.